# Why is this input valid

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Using [input.validity.valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState), why does my number input return valid for the value `0.` in this scenario?

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" step="1" value="0." id="one" /> <!--Valid??-->
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" step="1" value="0.0" id="two" /> <!--fine-->
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" step="1" value="0" id="three" /> <!--fine-->
```

Chrome 37.0.2062.103 m

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rL8q5t9/)

**Edit:**

Oddly, any negative number with a period at the end also breaks the validation:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" step="1" value="-14." id="one" />
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opyzuz04/)

Comment: you can add an explicit `pattern` attribute

Comment: @vsync I can't add a `pattern` attribute to a number input - it gets [ignored](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: Your profile pic suits your situation :)

Comment: The deleted answer had a useful fiddle in the comments for testing. Particularly because you get different results when you set things programmatically from when you type them into the input. Not sure who created it, but it's here http://jsfiddle.net/8pucueqr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Note: since this answer was written, the Chrome bug mentioned in #1 has been fixed and so now only #2 applies.*

There are actually two answers here:

1. there's a bug in Chrome which means a value like `0.` is not validated correctly when you enter/set it in an input field.
2. if you set an invalid value in the HTML markup, the browser is required to ignore it and set the value to the empty string, which is considered valid unless the field is marked `required`.

Strictly speaking, it is the first one that is causing the behaviour you are seeing, because it stops #2 from ever happening, but if the bug were fixed in Chrome then as the question stands (i.e. only dealing with the initial markup, not any subsequent user interaction), #2 would apply.

It's also worth noting that #2 is what causes the similar (but not identical) behaviour in Firefox.

#### 1. The Chrome bug

The reason for #1 is that Chrome is using different parsing algorithms in its `rangeUnderflow` detection and its `badInput` detection.

[`rangeUnderflow`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/html/forms/InputType.cpp&cl=GROK&l=252&gsn=parseToNumberOrNaN&rcl=1410361901) uses [`Decimal::fromString(...)`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/platform/Decimal.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=693) which returns `NaN` if the input ends in a `.` causing `rangeUnderflow` to return`false`:

```
if (!numericValue.isFinite())
   return false;
```

In contrast, [`badInput`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/html/forms/NumberInputType.cpp&cl=GROK&l=238&gsn=parseToNumberOrNaN&rcl=1410361901) uses [`StringToDoubleConverter::StringToDouble(...)`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/wtf/dtoa/double-conversion.cc&cl=GROK&l=428&gsn=parseToNumberOrNaN&rcl=1410361901) which basically ignores a trailing `.` so the input is not considered 'bad'.

According to [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number):

> A string is a **valid floating-point number** if it consists of:
>
> 1. Optionally, a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-).
> 2. One or both of the following, in the given order:
> 3. A series of one or more ASCII digits.
> 4. 1. A single U+002E FULL STOP character (.).
>    2. A series of one or more ASCII digits.

Note that 2.2.2 is not optional - i.e if you have a `.` you must have digits after it.

So it's the `badInput` that's incorrect. (If Chrome was at least consistent about treating `0.` as valid, the `rangeUnderflow` would then have been detected)

#### 2. Markup vs user input

**But** if/when they fix the bug in Chrome, with the HTML in the question, it will *still* show as valid. Why?

Take for example if you set `value="aaa"` in the HTML. The input will still show as valid, even though `aaa` would cause `badInput` to be `true`.

This is because while parsing/rendering the page, Chrome runs a *value sanitization algorithm* on the attribute value. When it sees a value that is not a [valid floating point number](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number), it must set the input's value to the empty string as required by [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29). And the empty string is considered valid unless the input is marked `required`. This currently doesn't occur in Chrome for `value="0."` because it (incorrectly) passes the value sanitization algorithm. However, if/when they fix the bug in Chrome, this is what you would expect to happen.

If you actually type `aaa` into the input, it will then show as invalid, i.e. `badInput===true`. Similarly, in Firefox, and in Chrome if/when they fix the bug, if you type `0.` into the field, it will give `badInput===true` and therefore `valid===false`.

Answer (score 3):

In [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29) it says:

> User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty
>   string that is not a valid floating-point number. If the user agent
>   provides a user interface for selecting a number, then the value must
>   be set to the best representation of the number representing the
>   user's selection as a floating-point number.

The spec goes on to say:

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the
>   element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty
>   string instead.

In Firefox the `value` in DOM is being set to an empty string for the first input.  This is a valid state).  If you want the first field to be invalid in this situation, [you must make it `required`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/3rL8q5t9/1/):

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" step="1" value="0." id="one" required />
```

The spec also says:

> **Constraint validation**: While the user interface describes input that the user agent cannot convert to a valid floating-point number, 
>   the control is suffering from bad input.

I think in this case what Firefox (32.0) is doing is correct as long as the `#one` input is not displaying the `0.` value.  In Firefox if I manually type the value `0.` into the `#one` input then it is correctly highlighted as invalid.

However in Chrome 38.0.2125.58 beta-m the `0.` value is displayed when the page has loaded even though `document.querySelector("#one").value` evaluates to an empty string.  This means it fails to be caught by both `required` as well as by the constraint validation.  I believe this is a bug in Chrome.

Comment: I read the spec too around what is deemed a valid floating point number. `0.` certainly seems as it should resolve to `0` and therefore cause the underflow flag to be set on the validity object. Looks like a bug to me too.

Comment: Actually @robertc the last paragraph is not correct. In Chrome, `document.querySelector("#one").value` returns `"0."` - see http://jsfiddle.net/qa9orh37/ . I went digging in the Chromium source and found the problem, it's an inconsistency between the parsing in `rangeUnderflow` and `badInput` - see my answer

Comment: @CupawnTae On my Windows PC at work I got the empty string, on my Linux laptop at home I see "0." like you do.  I'll check the work PC again tomorrow to check I didn't imagine anything :)

Comment: weird - I got `"0."` on Windows 7, on both Chrome 37.x and 38.x-beta. My money's on cosmic rays ;) Anyway, even though I'm getting `"0."` back (and `0` for `valueAsNumber`), it still gives `rangeUnderflow===false`, which bears out what I concluded from the Chrome source code.

Comment: @CupawnTae OK, I get `0.` on Windows 7 too.  I must have confused myself in one of the variations I tried yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `value` attribute for validation is being parsed using the html5 `valueAsNumber` feature. This has different rules from JavaScript, so that in FF32:

```
var el = document.createElement("input");
el.type = "number";
el.value = "1";
el.valueAsNumber;
/*
1
*/
```

but

```
var el = document.createElement("input");
el.type = "number";
el.value = "0.";
el.valueAsNumber;
/*
NaN
*/
```

If "0." is therefore being parsed as `NaN` I think the validation is bypassed.

Comment: Chrome correctly reports the number value of `"0."` as `0`, though. Also, other non-numeric values (e.g., `"aaa"`) which presumably also produce `NaN` values fail correctly, while `"0.` incorrectly passes. Perhaps `valueAsNumber` is part of the story, but it doesn't seem to explain the whole thing.

Comment: @apsillers actually, if you replace `"0."` in the second example with `"aaa"` it shows as valid in Chrome - seems to be a difference between setting the value in code and the user typing it into the input

Comment: Also, perhaps relatedly, if you set it programmatically to `"aaa"` in an input in the DOM, it shows up as blank, whereas `"0."` shows up onscreen. Presumably because while `"0."` is at least on its way to being a valid number, `"aaa"` is not.

Answer (score 0):

In input type number the containing **value** is a [floating-point number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html#input.number).

A [floating-point number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float) consists of the following parts, in exactly the following order:

1. Optionally, the first character may be a "-" character.
2. One or more characters in the range "0—9".
3. Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:

   1. a "." character
   2. one or more characters in the range "0—9"
4. Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:

   1. a "e" character or "E" character
   2. optionally, a "-" character or "+" character
   3. One or more characters in the range "0—9".

---

And you might know in floating-point number `0. == 0.0 == 0`. As others 0, 0.0 validation is fine, so `0.` is also a fine validation.

Comment: This answer does not seem to address the central issue that `0.0` correctly fails validation as less than `1`, but `0.` does not.

Comment: Also, according to the spec, `0.` is not a valid floating point number. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#valid-floating-point-number