# How can I prevent IE10 from automatically clearing out letters entered into a input type=number field?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-10, forms

Internet Explorer 10 clears out letters if entered in a input type=number field such as abcdef. Is there anyway to prevent this or to catch this event so that the user can be notified of what just happened? I'd prefer it behave like Chrome and Firefox and prompt the user when they click submit. Also why does it count a string such as 1abcdef as valid on form submit?

Comment: To answer your second question: because `parseFloat('1abcdef')` returns `1`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25787553/8655) has a lot of good stuff on how the parsing and validating of `number` inputs works.